# Calling from tables to x, y

Tags: function, lua, terminal, lua-table, love2d

I am again doing some lua (Love2D), and I want to call upon some tables as X/Y coordinates for my `love.graphics.rectangle`s. My code is like this.

```
function love.load()
 x=0
 y=0
 x2={}
 y2={}
end
function love.update(dt)
 if love.keyboard.isDown(" ") then
  table.insert(x2, x)
  table.insert(y2, y)
 end
end
function love.draw()
 for i,v in pairs(--What should I do here?--) do
  love.graphics.rectangle("fill", --How would I make these coordinates match the ones in the table?--)
 end
end
```

My code isn't like this, but it just shows what I'm going for.

Comment: Please state your question as text, not just buried in comments in your code.

Comment: What are `x` and `y`? Where/what are the coordinates you want to use in the `love.graphics.rectangle` call?

Comment: Lol sorry, in my actual code I have that taken care of. I just want to call the values in x2 and y2 and store them in the love.graphics.rectangle function, like love.graphics.rectangle("fill", x2value, y2value, 10, 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> love.graphics.rectangle("fill", --How would I make these coordinates match the ones in the table?--)

```
love.graphics.rectangle("fill", 0, 0)
```

Since you're always inserting 0 into the tables, that'll do that job.

Your code is so contrived it's almost impossible to tell what you're asking. What is the problem you're trying to solve? Specifically *why* do you want to put the x, y coordinates into a table? If your goal is to read the last inserted values from the respective tables, then do this:

```
love.graphics.rectangle("fill", x2[#x2], y2[#y2])
```

`#` is length operator, so `t[#t]` will get the last element in the table `t`.

Note that inserting into a table whenever the space bar is down is going to create a huge table very quickly.

Comment: Don't worry, I have a cooldown feature. Anyway, I have my reasons of doing this the way I am. Thanks for the answer btw, it worked.